# CSS applied properly on JBoss (OpenShift), but not on Tomcat 7

Tags: html, css, tomcat, jboss

I have a page which I load both on a local Tomcat 7 instance and a remote JBoss instance (OpenShift). The css is applied on JBoss, but not on Tomcat 7:

**Html page** head:

```
<head>
    <title><decorator:title /></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/reset.css" media="screen" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/960gs-16col.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/default.css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

**Default.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #c73b0b;
}
```

`rest.css` and `default.css` are not applied on Tomcat 7. I checked with FireBug, no bugs reported. I checked the page source code on both systems, exactly the same.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Silly guess, do the CSS load on Tomcat 7? I mean, there isn't any 404 in `Net` tab in Firebug?

Comment: You are right, there is a 404 for all 3 css... Why?

Comment: Mmmmm it goes straight to http://localhost:8080/static/css/reset.css and misses the application path...

Comment: `/static/css/reset.css` is an absolute path. If `reset.css` is part of the application, shouldn't be referenced as `static/css/reset.css`? (without the leading slash)

Comment: Thanks, create a solution and I'll approve it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we resolved together with @JVerstry:

Seems that Tomcat wasn't loading the CSS files the same way as JBoss.

`/static/css/reset.css` is an absolute path. If `reset.css` is part of the application, it should be referenced as `static/css/reset.css` (without the leading slash)

Answer (score 1):

You should always build URLs in a webapp like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= request.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/images/favicon.ico") %>" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

This will make your webapp trivially re-locatable when you change the context path, and solve problems like the one you have posed above.

Note that most URL-handling tag libraries like JSTL, Struts, etc. will all perform the above work for you. It's usually better to use one of those than have that ugly scriptlet everywhere in your JSP code.

Comment: What do you think about orique's comment about removing the leading /. Would that be enough?

Comment: I think it will come back to bite you. IMO you should always use absolute paths rooted at the context path: that way, the links always work no matter where the file is in the webapp and no matter what the base URL the client is using.